# ElFinder + Hide Directory

Tags: php, elfinder

I am currently using ElFinder 2.0 .

I want to hide some directory inside the main directory.

How can i do that?

I tried in **connector.php** file

but not succeeded.

This is my code

```
$opts = array(
    // 'debug' => true,
    'roots' => array(
        array(
            'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem', // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
            'path' => '/home/workioscProject/public_html/codensa/catalogo', // path to files (REQUIRED)
            'URL' => 'http://76.76.163.155/workioscProject/codensa/catalogo/', // URL to files (REQUIRED)
            'accessControl' => 'access'             // disable and hide dot starting files (OPTIONAL)
        ),
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        array(// hide anything else
            'pattern' => '!^/exportForms!',
            'hidden' => true
        )
    )
);

// run elFinder
$connector = new elFinderConnector(new elFinder($opts));
$connector->run();
```

What i do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$opts = array(
    // 'debug' => true,
    'roots' => array(
        array(
            'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem', // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
            'path' => '/home/workioscProject/public_html/codensa/catalogo', // path to files (REQUIRED)
            'URL' => 'http://76.76.163.155/workioscProject/codensa/catalogo/', // URL to files (REQUIRED)
            'accessControl' => 'access' ,            // disable and hide dot starting files (OPTIONAL)
            'attributes' => array(
                array(// hide anything else
                    'pattern' => '!^/exportForms!',
                    'hidden' => true
                )
            )
        ),
    )
);
```